# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) in OpenShift

Tags: macos, git, command-line, ssh, openshift

While trying to `ssh` into OpenShift (DIY instance), I am getting this message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

I did the following:

- I pasted the public key through the online interface in OpenShift.
- I was able to clone **and** push changes to the git repo they provided.
- The permissions for my private key is 400 (Even changed it to 600, 700 and 755 but no avail).
- Checked the known_hosts file and the instance info got added their already.
- `ssh -vv ssh://54191dcf5973cac267000c76@diy-jikslight.rhcloud.com 2&>
  c.log`
- Log file: [c.log](http://pastebin.com/cb5eDxgs)
- Ran `rhc setup` when nothing worked, but nothing changed.
- I am using OSX Mavericks, iTerm2 and zsh.

Any idea why this happens when my git pulls and pushes are accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging in the server using:
`$ ssh 54191dcf5973cac267000c76@diy-jikslight.rhcloud.com`

The above error comes when the server can't authenticate your private key. Make sure your current terminal's home directory has the private key whose public key pair resides on server.

Comment: Yes, had figured it out the `ssh://` prefix seemed to be the issue. Had the keys already. Thanks anyways.